# How can I get a big number in non-scientific notation?

Tags: python, formatting, number-formatting

I just tried

```
>>> 2.17 * 10**27
2.17e+27
>>> str(2.17 * 10**27)
'2.17e+27'
>>> "%i" % 2.17 * 10**27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
>>> "%f" % 2.17 * 10**27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
>>> "%l" % 2.17 * 10**27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: incomplete format
```

Now I ran out of ideas. I want to get

```
2170000000000000000000000000
```

How can I print such big numbers? (I don't care if it's a Python 2.7+ solution or a Python 3.X solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting your operator precedence wrong. You are formatting `2.17`, then multiplying that by a long integer:

```
>>> r = "%f" % 2.17
>>> r
'2.170000'
>>> r * 10 ** 27
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
```

Put parentheses around the multiplication:

```
>>> "%f" % (2.17 * 10**27)
'2169999999999999971109634048.000000'
```

This is one of the drawbacks of overloading the modulus operator for string formatting; the newer [*Format String syntax*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) used by the [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) it employs (and can be used with the [`format()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)) neatly skirt around that issue. I'd use `format()` for this case:

```
>>> format(2.17 * 10**27, 'f')
'2169999999999999971109634048.000000'
```

Comment: *sigh* Thank you. Now that I read your answer, it is obivous. Thank you for putting that many details in it!